# Validate Custom expression using Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, validation, npm-install

If I have a string like

```
${employee} and ${} should be validate
```

And I want to fetch all substring that contains the pattern like

`${}`

and validate as if string starting with ${ and } must have value?

suppose for below string

```
  ${employee} and ${} should be validate
```

it should return array with two element

[ ${employee}, ${} ]

and upon validate it should show the second element as invalid (as it is blank)

for this, I have tried the following code

```
function fetchMatches(theString, theRegex){
    return theString.match(theRegex).map(function(el) {
        var index = theString.indexOf(el);
        return [index, index + el.length - 1];
    });
}
fetchMatches(" ${employee} and ${} should be validate",/(\$)(\{)(.*)(\})/i);
```

but it is not returning the desired output.

guys, please suggest some help

Comment: This is not quite clear. If you need to only match non-empty `${xxx}` you may just use `/\${[^}]+}/g` regex. Then, you may just check the string with`indexOf('${}')`.

Comment: I want all substring which starts with **${** and ends with **}** and based upon output I want to check if any of substring is empty or not

Comment: Sorry, it is still unclear what exact output you want to get.

Comment: suppose for the string "${employee} and ${} should be validated" it should return an array as [${employee}, ${}]

Comment: and with output array, I want to check if string start with ${ and end with } must not be blank

Comment: So, that would be output like `Item at index N is empty`?

Comment: that is exact output. I want it for all substring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following solution: use `/\${[^{}]*}/g` regex with `String#match` to fetch all the matches, and then loop over the matches to check which have an empty value:

```js
var s = "${user.lastName}${user.firstName}${}";
var m, results = [];
var re = /\${[^{}]*}/g;
while ((m=re.exec(s)) !== null) {
  if (m[0] === "${}") {
    console.log("Variable at Index",m.index,"is empty.");
  } else {
    results.push(m[0]);
  }
}
console.log(results);
```

Since you mentioned that there can be nested values you may use `XRegExp`:

```js
var s = "${user.${}lastName}${user.firstName}${}";
var res = XRegExp.matchRecursive(s, '\\${', '}', 'g', {
  valueNames: [null, null, 'match', null]
});
for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
   if (~res[i]["value"].indexOf("${}") || res[i]["value"] == "") {
     console.log("The",res[i]["value"],"at Index",res[i]["start"],"is invalid.");
   } else {
     console.log("The",res[i]["value"],"at Index",res[i]["start"],"is valid.");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.1.1/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your update It is working fine just for Index position, it should be the position for the string.

Comment: also for string like ${user.${}lastName}${user.firstName}${}

Comment: Actually, `${user.lastName}${user.firstName}${}` is working well with the original suggestion. You did not mention that there can be nested values. How many nested levels can there be? Also, can you use a 3rd party library, like `XRegExp` then? XRegExp can handle nested structures.

Comment: What is the expected result for `${user.${}lastName}${user.firstName}${}`?

Comment: I just want to validate the expression. The final result should be valid.

Comment: I just am driving at the fact that native JS regex cannot match nested balanced structures. So, I am adding an XRegExp solution that you should be able to modify acc. to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the regex from

```
/(\$)(\{)(.*)(\})/
```

to

```
/(\$)(\{)[^\}]+(\})/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
\$\{(\w+)?\}
```

`(\w+)?` will consider the pattern whether there is character inside ${} or not

Comment: If you change `/i` to `/g`, I think it will give you both matches.